# Output text Yes or No if cell has a, and (b or C) and d in Excel

Tags: excel, if-statement, excel-formula

Cell a1 has letters a, b, c, d, e. I want to output in cell a2 yes or no based on what is identified in cell a1.

I can do: output yes if a, and b, and C are found in a1 by:

```
=IF(AND(ISNUMBER(SEARCH("*a*",A1)),ISNUMBER(SEARCH("*b*",A1)),ISNUMBER(SEARCH("*c*",A1))),"yes","no")
```

But I cannot do: output yes if a, and (b or C), and D are found in a1...

What formulae modification should I make?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Consider:

```
=IF(AND(ISNUMBER(SEARCH("a",A1)),ISNUMBER(SEARCH("b",A1)),OR(ISNUMBER(SEARCH("c",A1)),ISNUMBER(SEARCH("d",A1)))),"yes","no")
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `and()` and `or()` too.

```
=IF(AND(ISNUMBER(SEARCH("a", A1)), 
 OR(ISNUMBER(SEARCH("b", A1)), ISNUMBER(SEARCH("c", A1))), 
 ISNUMBER(SEARCH("d", A1))), "yes", "no")
```